# ANTLR4: Error when I try to find which parser subrule matched

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I've got a parser rule like this, and I need to know which subrule matched:

```
dt returns [DT v]
:    (d1=date t1=time?|t2=time d2=date?)
                 {if ($d1 == null) // right side matched ... }
;
```

I get an ANTLR4 error message: "missing attribute access on rule reference 'd1' in '$d1'".

I can get rid of this error by putting e.g. `$d1.v`, but then I get a `NullPointerException` at runtime in ANTLR-generated code at

```
if (((DtrContext)_localctx).d1.v != null)
```

because `_localctx.d1` is null, so `_localtx.d1.v` uses a null ptr.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this impass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context object for `d1` (parse tree node of type `DateContext`) can be referenced with `$d1.ctx`. This is equivalent to what you were assuming `$d1` alone would do.

Comment: Thanks, impass bypassed. I see that the ANTLR-generated code turns ($d1.ctx == null) into (d == null), so I wonder what stops my assumption about the syntax from being the syntax?